# How do I get the grey color/translucency I see on UIPickerDate default view on my own custom Picker?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uipickerview

I have created a UI Picker but the default is just it being transparent. I would like to use/be given the RGB + translucency values that makes the grey color that is commonly used on picker views.

It is the same grey like the defualt color for a programmatic UI Date Picker. Thank you! I need this to be in alignment with Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.

Added a picture of the background color/translucency I need below:

[image]

Comment: Try to change the tint color of UIPicker.

Comment: I know how to change to different color of the UI Picker, but I'm wondering what exact color is that grey.

Comment: can someone explain why I am getting murked with downvotes as well):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iPhone SDK has two types of gray color both have opacity 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BJTm.png)

iOS 13 also introduces a range of six opaque gray colors you can use in rare cases where translucency doesn't work well.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/

And for changing the background color.

**light gray color:**

```
picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
```

**dark gray color:**

```
picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

if you want some transparency on the picker view. You can add Gradient on it.

```
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: picker.frame.width, height: picker.frame.height))
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

        gradient.frame = view.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.lightGray.cgColor]

        picker.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

find the image as it looks with gradient and light gray color.
[picker view with gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE0Ch.png)

Comment: defiantly not the right grey much too dark, and It's not a problem on how to set the color I know how thanks though

Comment: I'm familiar with the system .lightgray and .darkgray ui colors, however these are not the right color/opacity

Comment: uploaded a picture @Animesh

Comment: Thanks, @Matteo. Can you please explain more, if possible "Added a picture of the color I need below:"

Comment: That nice-looking, slightly translucent grey that is as the backgroundcolor on the picker view.

Comment: @Matteo Please check now?

Comment: Ok, @Matteo. Then what else you want please explain.

Comment: The only thing that I want is still the same question I've originaly asked. To be given the rgb and whatever translucency values it takes to show the standard ui date picker background color as shown above. @Animesh

Comment: I need this because of human interface guidelines, Apple defianlty does not want different color for picker views that do almost the same function

Answer (score -1):

Hex color - #e8e9ed

RGB color - UIColor(red: 232/255, green: 233/255, blue: 237/255, alpha: 1)

or you can use #f7f7f7

I hope it works.

Comment: It's close but not the same, the system one has some transparency to it.

Comment: uploaded a photo @Rushang Patel

Comment: if you want some transparency then add a gradient layer.